# Find the letter 'z' within three characters after an 'a'

Tags: strings, ruby

It works, just feel that my solution is too complicated.

```
# Write a method that takes a string in and returns true if the letter
# "z" appears within three letters **after** an "a". You may assume
# that the string contains only lowercase letters.
#
# Difficulty: medium.

def nearby_az(string)

  i = 0
  while i < string.length

    if string[i] == "a"
      a_index = i
    end

    if string[i] == "z"
      z_index = i
    end

    if (a_index) && (z_index) && (a_index < z_index) && ((z_index - a_index) <= 3)
      return true
    end
    i += 1
  end
  return false
end

# These are tests to check that your code is working. After writing
# your solution, they should all print true.

puts('nearby_az("baz") == true: ' + (nearby_az('baz') == true).to_s)
puts('nearby_az("abz") == true: ' + (nearby_az('abz') == true).to_s)
puts('nearby_az("abcz") == true: ' + (nearby_az('abcz') == true).to_s)
puts('nearby_az("a") == false: ' + (nearby_az('a') == false).to_s)
puts('nearby_az("z") == false: ' + (nearby_az('z') == false).to_s)
puts('nearby_az("za") == false: ' + (nearby_az('za') == false).to_s)
```

Comment: This question would fit [codegolf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) too.

Answer (score 4):

Riffing on [@Shepmaster's excellent answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/119354/32521):

```
def nearby_az(string)
  !!string.match(/a.{,2}z/)
end

['baz', 'abz', 'abcz'].each do |s|
  puts "nearby_az('#{s}') expect true: #{nearby_az(s)}"
end
['a', 'z', 'za'].each do |s|
  puts "nearby_az('#{s}') expect false: #{nearby_az(s)}"
end
```

Comment: I'd use `each` instead of `for` (not unidiomatic in Ruby). And 2 spaces.

Comment: Good call. Edited (hopefully along the lines you meant :)).

Comment: Ruby style guide says to avoid `!!`. <https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-bang-bang>. An easier way to to convert to boolean is `string.match(/a.{,2}z/).present?`. Also note that the `return` is superfluous.

Comment: @Quuxplusone: just drop this `return` and that's it.

Comment: @dankohn `present?` is method added by Rails; it doesn't exist in vanilla Ruby. But you're right that `!!` should be avoided

Comment: @tokland Dropped. :)

Answer (score 1):

This could be a good opportunity to use a regular expression:

```
def nearby_az(string)
  !!(string.match(/az/) || string.match(/a.z/) || string.match(/a..z/))
end
```

I didn't spend any time to see if this could be made more efficient; I mostly focused on understandability.

I would not normally have converted to a Boolean (using `!!`) except that your tests *explicitly* check for `true` or `false`. Returning `nil` or non-`nil` for truthy values is idiomatic Ruby. A *predicate method* should also end with a question mark: `nearby_az?`.

Additionally, your output printing at the end is not idiomatic. I'd expect to see something like this:

```
puts "nearby_az('baz') == true: #{nearby_az('baz')}"
```

Specifically, there's no need to compare a Boolean result to the `true` literal, and then using *string interpolation* allows you to avoid the `to_s` call. Even better would be to use a testing framework for tests. This would allow you to avoid repeating yourself in the string and the call.

Answer (score 1):

Not in ruby, but just to give a suggestion on how to do this without the use of regEx.

```
private bool CheckIfCharsIsWithin(string text, char char1, char char2, int maxCharsBetween)
{
    int chars = maxCharsBetween;
    foreach (var character in text)
    {
        chars++;
        if (char1.Equals(character))
        {
            chars = 0;
        }else if (char2.Equals(character) && chars <= maxCharsBetween)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Things that can improve the code (IMO):

- Replace `while` with `.each_char.with_index` and get rid of `i = 0` and `i += 1`
- All of your `if` statements has only one condition, in this case you can get rid of the `end` and write it like `a_index = i if string[i] == "a"`
- You don't need to use `return` explicitly on the last line, so instead of `return false` only `false` should do the trick, as Ruby always returns the last line's evaluation
- If I'm going to refactor your code using same logic I would do it like:

  ```
  def nearby_az(string)
    # adding guard clause, in case the string doesn't contain 'a' or 'z' return false
    return false unless string.include?('a') && string.include?('z')

    a_index = 0
    z_index = 0

    string.each_char.with_index do |char, index|
      a_index = index if char == 'a'
      z_index = index if char == 'z'

      return true if a_index < z_index && (z_index - a_index) <= 3
    end

    false
  end
  ```

Comment: @mdfst13 yes, you are right. I only tested this code using the tests provided with the original code.

Comment: @mdfst13 I moved the `if` statement inside the loop, that should return true as soon as the condition is met, so `nearby_az('azbcdz')` will be `true`, thanks a lot for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a ruby guy, so I won't try to review style, etc.  But on the matter of making this code shorter, I have a suggestion.

> ```
>     if string[i] == "z"
>       z_index = i
>     end
>
>     if (a_index) && (z_index) && (a_index < z_index) && ((z_index - a_index) <= 3)
>       return true
>     end
> ```

What does the `z_index` variable do for you?  Consider the following code instead:

```
    if (a_index) && (string[i] == "z") && (a_index < i) && ((i - a_index) <= 3)
      return true
    end
```

And I'm not sure that you actually need the `&& (a_index < i)` portion.  If you've seen `a_index`, it must be less than `i` because you are iterating up and the current character is not `"a"` but `"z"`.  So

```
    if (a_index) && (string[i] == "z") && ((i - a_index) <= 3)
      return true
    end
```

should be sufficient.

Now you don't need to manage `z_index` at all.

If you don't want to check if `a_index` exists on every iteration, you could say

```
    if (string[i] == "z") && (a_index) && ((i - a_index) <= 3)
      return true
    end
```

That would only ever do fewer comparisons than the original code.  Whether it's faster than the previous version probably depends on the input.  If `a_index` is normally not set, then the previous version doesn't even have to check for `"z"`.

You could make `a_index` set less frequently if you move the `((i - a_index) <= 3)` check into an `if`/`else` inside the other `if`.  Then you could clear `a_index` whenever you've already gone at least three characters past it.  That kind of optimization would only really be helpful in long strings though, not your example tests.

Comment: You might also prepare `a_index` less than `-3` before entering the loop, then drop the test for `a_index` presence.

Answer (score 0):

Combining the existing answers, what you want is basically:

```
def nearby_az(string)
  string =~ /a.{,2}z/
end
```

Now, this doesn't return `true`/`false`; it'll return `nil` (which is false'y) or the index of the first match (which is truth'y).

In regular Ruby, that's what you'd use.

If you want booleans specifically, you can use one of these lines instead:

```
!(string =~ /a.{,2}z/).nil?
!string.match(/a.{,2}z/).nil?
```

or you could even use one of these:

```
string =~ /a.{,2}z/ ? true : false
string.scan(/a.{,2}z/).any?
```

but those are sort of roundabout way of doing things.

And, if you want it to be case-insensitive, use this pattern:

```
/a.{,2}z/i
```

That's about it.